# Anko Layout Preview Plugin Could Not use

Tags: android, intellij-idea, anko

I'm using Anko Layout to code my Android UI instead of XML.
It's convenient to have layout preview when we code Android UI.
There is Anko Support plugin can be install

[image]

But after I installed this plugin in **Android Studio(version-2.3.3)** or **IntelliJ Idea(17.2 or 16)** my project can not load.
 I search from GitHub, I find this

[image]

But it does not work on Android Studio 3.0 Beta

Is there anyone with the same problem like me, who can tell me which version of Android Studio or IntelliJ Idea can use this plugin normal?

Comment: anko layout preview can be used in Android Studio 3.0 Now!!!But,everytime after you code anko dsl,you need to make project so that preview can be updated!

Comment: I don't see the option in the AS 3.0 =/